# Java: incremental filtering in Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, filtering

We're solving a problem where we need to fetch unique data from DB using a set of conditions. The idea is to fetch using the most general conditions first (as it's the fastest). If it returns only one item, great; if it returns multiple items, then we need to filter that data by incrementally applying more and more conditions until it gives us only one result.

Does Spring/Hibernate or any other library already provide something similar to what we want to do?

Comment: Do the filters follow a predetermined sequence?

Comment: do the first fetch from db and do the rest of the filtering in your code?

Comment: @Arvind Sridharan we will do it in the code (hence the mention of Spring/Hibernate), but wanted to know if there's some library that does the plumbing/boilerplate work so we can configure it only with our filters.

Comment: Not sure if such a library exists, if it doesn't, your best bet is to probably implement your filters as decorators using the decorator pattern, as you mention they are linked serially.

Comment: @Jeshurun thanks for the idea. We're thinking of using 'chain of responsibility' which was sparked off by your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using rule based programming to handle this, but chances are that will be over engineering your solution.